# Disable banner for minor issues in SonarLint

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint

I recently installed SonarLint in IDEA 2016.2 and it has been very helpful, but one minor annoyance is the banner for a minor issue won't go away.  I realize that this is an issue that needs to be addressed, but I can't control the Sonar project settings and updating all these files would involve doing a huge commit.  I know how to disable the syntax highlighting for minor errors, but how to disable the banner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, that's not possible.

The plan is to track issues when connected to a SonarQube server and hide issues that are marked as resolved: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-83

In your case, you wil be able to mark all minor issues in those files as "won't fix".